# Can a service be bound to more than one component?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have been working with Android Services for a while now. I know how to start a service and bind to a service. I understand that you can bind to more than one service for instance in an activity, but can a service be bound to more than one component (more than one activity, more than one service or for instance an activity and an other service) in the same application?

The reason for my question is that I have a `LocationService.java` class that extends `Service` and is responsible for getting location updates. The value received for the current location is supposed to be used in a couple of other components. For now, I am binding `LocationService` in `Service A` and I am using `ICallback` and `ServiceConnection`. I want to do the same in `Service B` in order to receive location updates.

Should I proceed to bind `LocationService` in `Service B` using the same model as in `Service A`, and if so, should I start `LocationService` again in `Service B`? Could I use a `BroadcastReceiver` instead?

Comment: Ever heard of [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)  ? You have to change your over all model to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your problem and the task you want to achieve. You are updating the location from the Activity A and same you want to achieve in Activity B. As you have already implemented the whole process in Activity A so implementing the same in Activity B would not make any sense. As the prime concept of OOPs is code re usability so you just Broadcast the result from Activity A and add a Broadcast receiver in Activity B.This would be far more easy and will not give the load to your app.

Comment: You can show your appreciation by up voting the answer @facilitator